# directory with automatic time in it in unix shell

Tags: unix, date, time, directory

I want to create script where newly generated directory automatically have the current time as part of name.

syntax

```
mkdir mydir[min-hour-day-month-year]
```

thus the recent directory will be named as

```
mydir101718052012
```

directory created after one hour

```
mydir111718052012
```

and so on.

Sorry for simple question, I am new to unix and I using bash

Edits: Why is not following correct ? How can I do it ?

```
newdir = mydir$( date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
cp new.txt newdir/new1.txt
```

Comment: I would suggest reversing the order, and adding second: year-month-day-hour-min-sec -- this way sorting alphanumerically also sorts by date. In terms of adding seconds -- are you sure that you don't want to add two directories in the same minute?

Comment: it is great comment...although I am not expecting two directory at the same min ...but it would nice to add sec...and I am for year first now

Comment: bash separates tokens by whitespace -- so `newdir = mydir$( date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)` needs a space before the closing peren: `newdir = mydir$( date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following functions set up in my bash startup scripts:

```
# Date Time Stamp
dts() { date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S; }

# Date mkdir
dmkdir() { mkdir $(dts); }
```

I use them chiefly on the command line, if you want to run them inside a script, you'll have to either source the startup script or define the shell functions within the script. If you wanted to prepend a name (e.g. `mydir`), you could easily give it an argument like this:

```
# Date mkdir
dmkdir() { mkdir "$@$(dts)"; }
```

This would be called like this:

```
$ dmkdir mydir
$ ls -d mydir*
mydir2012-05-18-11-38-40
```

This does mean that if your argument list contains spaces, they will show up in the directory name, which might or might not be a good thing.

You can assign a shell variable inside the shell function, this can be accessed outside the function:

```
dmkdir() { newdir="$@$(dts)"; mkdir $newdir; }
```

Used like this:

```
$ dmkdir mydir
$ cd $newdir
$ pwd
/tmp/mydir2012-05-18-12-54-32
```

This is very handy, but there are a couple of things that you have to be careful of: 1) you're polluting your namespace -- you may overwrite a shell variable called `$newdir` created by a different process 2) It's very easy to forget which variable dmkdir is going to write to, especially if you have a lot of shell functions writing out variables. A good naming convention will help a lot with both issues.

Another option is to have the shell function echo the directory name:

```
dmkdir() { local newdir="$@$(dts)"; mkdir $newdir && echo $newdir; }
```

This can be called as follows:

```
newdir="$(dmkdir mydir)"
```

`local` means that `$newdir` isn't available outside of dmkdir, which is a Good Thing(TM).

The use of `&&` means that you only echo the name of the directory if the directory creation is successful.

The `$()` syntax allows you to load anything echoed to STDOUT to be loaded into a variable, and the single quotes ensure that if there are any spaces in the directory name, it still gets loaded into a single variable.

This gets around the namespace pollution problems inherent in the previous solution.

Comment: thank you; I have simple question - how can assign a value to newly created directory (for example 'newdirectory'), so that I can use it downstream in the script for example 'cp xfile.txt /newdirectory'

Comment: I got an error when I did  - newdir = dmkdir mydir, as want to store the name of directory am I missing something obivious ?

Answer (score 6):

If your implementation of date supports these options you can simply do:

```
mkdir mydir$( date +%M%H%d%m%Y )
```

Note that this does not insert hyphens in the name as per your sample output.  To get the hyphens as in your initial description:

```
mkdir mydir$( date +%M-%H-%d-%m-%Y )
```